# Is full attribution required when quoting parts of the question in an answer?

Tags: discussion, legal, attribution

I know that using content from Stack Overflow requires attribution. I am also aware that that attribution is required even when quoting other answers *on the same page*. I came across a post today which needed some edits. As is typical when I edit a question, I was going through the rest of the thread, seeing where else edits could be made and noticed that an answer had quoted a part of the question (without attribution). I tried a few ways to edit the attribution into the answer, but I was unable to come up with a way that didn't just make noise.

I assume the same attribution requirements would apply to quoting the question just the same as would quoting an answer. Having said that, I have never seen attribution provided in an answer to the question *on the same page* (that I can recall). (I am also certain that I have missed providing attribution to the question I have answered if this is indeed required.)

My question is **not**: is including full attribution to the question on the same page a good idea? Because, in this case it seems to be rather implicit that the quote is from the question itself and added noise to the answer body itself.

My question **is**: is full attribution required when quoting parts of the question being answered in the answer body?

---

The [licensing section of Stack Overflow's Terms of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing) states:

> You should be aware that all Public Content you contribute is available for public copy and redistribution, and all such Public Content must have appropriate attribution.

To me this indicates that attribution would be required as Questions are part of "all Public Content", however, the issue for me is the word "appropriate," in that, is it "appropriate" to omit such attribution within the Q/A format when an answer is clearly in response to the question?

I do not know if this information is controlling, but there is a [blog article from 2009-06-25 by Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/) that outlines requirements in this way:

> So let me clarify what we mean by **attribution**. If you republish
> this content, we **require** that you:
>
> 1. **Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow or the Stack Exchange network** in some way. It doesn’t have to be obnoxious;
>    a discreet text blurb is fine.
> 2. **Hyperlink directly to the original question** on the source site (e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
> 3. **Show the author names** for every question and answer
> 4. **Hyperlink each author name** directly back to their user profile page on the source site (e.g.,
>    http://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)

The [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) in the Stack Overflow answering help section, conversely, only mentions citing other answers and outside sources (emphasis mine):

> When you find a useful resource that can help answer a question
> (**from another site or in an answer on Stack Overflow**) make sure
> you do all of the following:
>
> - Provide a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links) to the original page or answer
> - [Quote](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) only the relevant portion
> - Provide the name of the original author

This does not seem to include Questions explicitly, but perhaps this is because it is already covered by the general requirements and its explicit addition is unnecessary.

Comment: From a layman's POV, I would argue no, since answers are posted in _direct response_ to the quoted content (the question); attribution would seem implicit at that point. But that may not hold actual legal water... This is a really interesting question regardless!

Comment: As a separate but similar aside, if I quoted your above post in this very _comment_, is/ should "full attribution" also be required here too? Or is that also implicit?

Comment: I would say _if_ it is required in an answer it would also be required in a comment (?) but that is also a good question.

Comment: It shouldn't be and I can't imagine it is. It would mean that a very high percentage of all SO answers are doing it wrong. Should that be the case I'm sure someone would have reacted long ago.

Comment: Maybe this question also highlights why a more permissive license like MIT as content license for SO would have been a better choice. Everyone argues that attribution everywhere is not convenient, so maybe a license that would be more convenient by design would have been a better way. Unfortunately that train already left.

Comment: @4386427 "Should that be the case I'm sure someone would have reacted long ago." You'd be suprised. Even the company itself (or at least parts of it) didn't know exactly what license the content was under for some time in the past.

Comment: It seems to me that providing attribution on the same exact page that attribution would point to would be redundant, as the URL for the attribution would land you on the same page you're currently on.

Comment: Questions can be edited - answers quoting the questions may get out of sync with it. So if you really want a secure way to quote it explicitly you would probably need to reference the history of the question to make clear as to what edition of it your quote is from ...

Comment: By this technicality, if I edit someone else's post, should I give attribution for the parts of their post that I leave in?

Comment: @khelwood If you edit a post you create a derived work. Attribution is given by the post history (it's not just nice to see the history, it's probably a must). Now the question is if a whole page on SO consists of a single work or of many multiple works. Why do people give attribution to comments that are on the same page? Maybe that wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: It's a pity that the Terms of Service do not really say much about what constitutes a single item of content on SO. It only speaks of questions and answers "The Stack Overflow Network is a set of related Internet sites and other applications for questions and answers ..." but not of question and answer pairs. In the end it comes down to what I actually do when clicking edit or add. Do I edit the whole page, the whole database or only parts of a page or do I just submit changesets or maybe something completely different?

Comment: I think it's just assumed that an answer can quote (or modify) things from a question.  We're not doing a PhD dissertation here (which I've done by the way)

Comment: @JosephDoggie "...it's just assumed that an answer can quote (or modify) things from a question..." That definitely seems to be approach of the currently highest voted answer. (It's not convenient, ergo I won't do it.) But with legal matters usually it doesn't works the way that we can vote what is right. Either there is a reason that it's okay or it's not. If only the license of the content would have omitted the BY clause of CC (but it didn't). Life would be easier.

Comment: @Trilarion -- if there are legal issues, I don't have any special expertise in that field.   The appropriate people could, however,  add a disclaimer to the SO legal agreement that when posting a question, anything posted could be used or modified in the answers.  (i.e. it is a risk the questioner would take).   At some point, however, the OP wants help, so the OP should assume that what is posted is free to be copied, or more likely modified.

Comment: Often people say things like "to correct your code" which has implicit attributions anyway.  I think someone else has said (I don't have an attribution) that you don't have to attribute a "for loop" -- it's just assumed.

Comment: I’d prefer you rather dodge the problem and avoid quoting the question in your answer in the first place. It’s right there on the same page, you don’t need to repeat it; it can come off as very antagonistic or condescending to individually respond to every other sentence fragment; it makes things look awkward if the question is later edited (e.g. to correct typos); and it’s simply lazy writing. Respond to the ideas in the question, not to the particular phrasing.

Comment: @JosephDoggie "..if there are legal issues.." If there weren't we could simply choose what is most convenient. It seems to come down to, is there a legal issue? That's what the question is asking. zcoop98's answer goes into this stuff but hinges on some leeway that's given in the license text. It may be reasonable or it may not be. I don't know.

Comment: I think you're going to get a lot of responses which seek to justify our lazy past behavior. It's probably all supposed to be attributed. Eek...

Comment: This question & the current answers presume that the OP of the question has done their due diligence, and has properly quoted & attributed any material that they haven't created themself. That's not necessarily true, although admittedly it's not so common on SO as it is on various other sites on the network. It's a bit difficult to properly attribute text when its author isn't who you think it is. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring " It's a bit difficult to properly attribute text when its author isn't who you think it is." Well mistakes happen and with regard to attribution and licensing in general they basically proliferate, but that's no reason not to give your best and try to do things as right as possible and to try to rectify things once you realize there has been an error somewhere in the past.

Comment: @Trilarion I agree. I just wanted to point out that we can't always assume that unattributed content in the question is the OP's own work, and that adds an extra wrinkle to the issues being discussed here.

Comment: @canon yet in all those many years, nobody cared. No regular site users, no site owners, no lawyers, nobody. We now have a gigantic library of pre-existing answers in which many answers will quote bits from the question without (express) attribution and everyone just let it happen for years and years. So no, I would find it highly doubtful that it is required.

Comment: @Gimby _"[...]  nobody cared. No regular site users, no site owners, no lawyers, nobody."_ Because it hasn't surfaced on meta... or because you have some knowledge of the SE side of things (maybe their legal team)? Just curious what drives the certainty of that statement.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I dug in a bit, and am going to argue that the answer is actually ***no*** (though I'm no lawyer by any stretch), our standard attribution requirements are not required for quotes of a question in an answer to that question.

My argument is 2-fold:

1. CC BY-SA 4.0 has a **reasonability clause**, which allows all attribution requirements to be fulfilled *as reasonable* to the means, medium, and context of the re-use.
2. Answers on Stack Exchange are always posted in direct relation to a question, which means the *context* of an answer allows it to omit otherwise required attribution details for question quotes in this case.

Full breakdown follows below.

---

#### Licenses and Attribution

Via [CreativeCommons.org's own wiki on the subject](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/best_practices_for_attribution#Title.2C_Author.2C_Source.2C_License), "full" attribution comes in *4 parts*:

- Title - What's the material?
- Author - Who authored the material?
- Source - Where can I find the material?
- License - How can I use the material?

What each of these entails and how they do or don't apply comes down to the specific CC license used on the given work or material. Here on Stack Exchange, we use [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)<sup>1</sup> to license new<sup>2</sup> material, which includes answers, questions, comments, tag wikis, etc.

This specific license allows anyone and everyone complete freedom to share and adapt the licensed content as long as they *attribute* the content and share it under the *same license* as the original content (or a *[compatible](https://creativecommons.org/share-your-work/licensing-considerations/compatible-licenses)* [license](https://creativecommons.org/share-your-work/licensing-considerations/compatible-licenses), which for CC BY-SA 2.0+ includes all later versions of CC BY-SA).

#### CC BY-SA Attribution Specifics

For CC BY-SA 4.0, here are [the specific requirements for attribution](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/License_Versions#Detailed_attribution_comparison_chart) from CC itself:

| Requirement | 4.0 License Details |
| --- | --- |
| Author(s) | "Creator if supplied and attribution parties if designated in reasonable manner" |
| Copyright Notice | "Copyright notice if supplied" |
| Title | "N/A" |
| Liability | "Notice that refers to Public License and notice that refers to the disclaimer of warranties if supplied" |
| Location | "To the extent practicable, URI or link to the material if supplied" |
| Modification | "Indicate if you modified the material; retain an indication of previous modifications" |
| License | "Indicate the material is available under Public License and include text/URI/link" |
| Attribution Removal | "Remove attribution information upon request to the extent reasonably practicable" |

<sup>(Right-hand column contents quoted from the Creative Commons Wiki, licensed under CC BY-SA 4.0)</sup>

*...That sounds like a lot right?* Well it is! Attribution is important, and needs to be thorough. That said, that's a **ton** of information to put in every context, and could get very noisy and burdensome in many situations.

Thankfully, Creative Commons considered this, and v4.0 includes an explicit escape hatch for such instances ([quoted from CC wiki](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/License_Versions#Attribution_reasonable_to_means.2C_medium.2C_and_context), emphasis mine):

> In 4.0, the manner of attribution is explicitly allowed to be reasonable to the **means**, **medium**, and **context** of how one shares a work.

In other words, *context matters* for attribution, as does how the work is delivered and presented. [That same wiki goes on to clarify](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/License_Versions#Reasonableness_applies_to_all_attribution_requirements) that *all* attribution requirements in v4.0 are subject to this reasonability clause.

Does that mean we can just omit credit entirely when it isn't convenient? Of course not! But it does mean that the attribution requirements aren't necessarily rigid and the same in all contexts, for all mediums, and in all places.

#### Our Context & "Reasonable" Attribution

Since the inclusion of all of the above attribution requirements is receptive to the means, medium, and context of the work (in this case, a digital post made on Stack Overflow), it's important to consider what the means, medium, and context even is exactly:

An answer post on Stack Exchange is always made in direct relation to a question, it's always posted on the same Q&A page as that question (even if hidden behind pagination), and the attribution details for the question itself are all easily accessible on that same page.

Given this, in light of the reasonability clause above, I argue that quoting a question's text in an answer, and denoting it as such, **is** CC BY-SA attribution fulfilled reasonable to **our** *means, medium, and context*. No further attribution or verbiage required.

---

<sup>1 - That's the *[Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 International Public License](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/legalcode)*, if you feel verbose and fancy.</sup>
<sup>2 - Some older material on Stack Exchange is licensed under CC BY-SA versions 2.5 or 3.0.</sup>

Comment: Does your included table meet the requirements for attribution? You have the location and I don't think anything else. Regardless, I think showing a reasonable attribution would enhance your answer.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Fair point, but I believe I am actually. The wiki happens to be licensed under CC BY-SA 4.0; I've linked it & mentioned where I got it from, mentioned who wrote it (CC organization), and this post is licensed under the same license. The quotes indicate that I haven't modified the text, and I think the copyright notice condition is covered under the post's copyright notice provided automatically in the share dialogue. I better highlighted that I got it and the other blockquote from the CC wiki though, at your request.

Answer (score 40):

> My question is: is full attribution required when quoting parts of the question being answered in the answer body?

On the internet, it is a standard convention when replying to a post in the same thread to simply include the part you're replying to in a block quote, as above, with no explicit attribution. This is likely because most software for email or forums will automatically include the original post in a block quote when you click the "reply" button, with a space for you to write a response underneath it. It is so conventional to do this, that when you read my answer, you *know* that the block-quoted text is from the question I'm answering.

So the fact that it's block-quoted and not explicitly attributed in the rest of the text, *means* it is a quote from the question, and we all understand it to mean that. So I think the quote *is* attributed to the question by the block-quote formatting.

Comment: Even if this answer is not *legally* correct, I do hope it's accepted by the community as being "correct". This is already the *de facto* standard on SO for quoting text from the question in answers. Also, I hope this is ok for purely pragmatic reasons; I have no desire to go through, and edit in attribution to, potentially hundreds of my own answers.

Comment: @cigien Since I'm not a lawyer I can't attest to it. But as a thought experiment, imagine someone suing the author of an academic article for quoting them "without attribution". The author's defense is that the quote was followed by a number 5 in square brackets, and that (combined with the complainant's name at number 5 in a list on a different page) is conventionally understood to be an attribution. I would think that's a slam-dunk defense for the author and the complainant would be laughed out; and it seems quite analogous.

Comment: Full agree, and I like how succinct you've put it. I just spent too long digging into the specific language of the license in [my own answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412960), and I believe it completely backs up this idea. Quotes in this context provide attribution reasonable to the context.

Comment: I knew that an answer like this would be popular. Especially since it seems to both confirm the way I've always seen it done, and also aligns with my personal preference for how attribution _should_ be done in this case. Having said this... my question is not "how should we handle this type of attribution" (wherein I fully agree with this answer) but rather "what is required by the additional attribution requirements imposed by Stack Exchange on its content." I would still like a definitive answer on what the actual _requirement_ is as the policies/terms are currently written.

Comment: @HenryEcker My answer is meant as an argument for why this way of doing it *is* sufficient to meet the requirements of attribution - I'm saying that because it's understood as a convention, block-quote formatting *is* attribution in this context. I don't think I can write a definitive answer since I'm not a lawyer; but a definitive legal answer would depend on knowing how a court would interpret the license, and it's pretty certain that no court has ever been asked this question, so I doubt a lawyer can give a truly definitive answer either.

Comment: I agree that block quoting is a form of attribution (again largely understood with context and is done in many online forums). My comment was to convey that I do know if this is a _legally_ valid argument. I don't know how a block quote alone (even with this conventional understanding) could meet all 3 requirements for "appropriate" attribution listed in referencing help/licensing documents and quoted in the question above.

Comment: That is certainly a fair point as well. This may not be a question that has a definitive answer if this question has never been raised before. I am surprised that the Stack Exchange documents seem to focus so much on answers, but almost none on the questions. But perhaps there has just been an implicit understanding so no one thought to question it before? In any case I do appreciate your answer @kaya3 and I echo the sentiments of cigien in that I would prefer this be the way the community chooses to interpret the attribution requirements.

Comment: I largely agree with this, but blockquote formatting is also commonly used for quotations that *aren't* from the OP. Worse yet, I've even seen people use that formatting as a kind of emphasis, roughly like headers or "TL;DR" notes. So although in some sense we "know" that a blockquote means a quotation from the OP, that "knowledge" is often wrong!

Comment: @ruakh That's true, some people use block quotes incorrectly, but it's still true that this is what block quotes are widely understood to mean; similarly, there are plenty of people who say "thanks in advanced" but this doesn't change the meaning of the word "advanced". To be clear, the convention I'm describing is not that block quotes always mean this, it's specifically about a block quote folllowed by a response to the quoted text, where the quoted text is not otherwise explicitly attributed.

Comment: You seem to have cause and effect back to front - mail and news software started providing an option to quote the replied-to message to automate and simplify something that users were already doing.

Comment: @TobySpeight I don't propose that the practice originated because of this feature in email/forum software, but the prevalence of this feature is probably largely responsible for it becoming such a widely-understood convention.

Comment: Maybe block quoting is sufficient, but what do you do for *code* you copy from the question?  You can't block quote code.  I very often include large parts of code from the question so that there will be a familiar context for my answer.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes you can block quote code. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69385163/using-a-lottieview-inside-navigationbaritems/69397898#69397898 for an example (although this is only one line of code, it is not inline tagging, e.g. with the ` character). Here's one with more lines of code using the triple ` tag instead of four space indentation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69079432/build-a-class-the-returns-a-line-graph-according-to-user-input/69090442#69090442

Comment: @TylerH interesting, it's not at all obvious that styles can be combined that way.

Answer (score 5):

<sup>**Disclaimer: IANAL**</sup>

Maybe... But it's easier than you think.

When you answer the question, your answer is permanently tied to the question. Also, the question is nearly always viewable with the link to your answer. Therefore, I think a hyperlink is not necessary for attribution.

Rather, the only attribution required by an answer when referring to the question is an indication that the content is from the asker.

As such the following is sufficient:

> The following line in **your** code references the `System.Cars2.EatBeans()`.
>
> ```
> // Eat beans at Cars 2 movie
> Movie.EatBeans();
> ```

Since your answer is in direct response and is on the same page, the pronoun "your" should be sufficient to attribute the question author, since it is in direct response to the question. Anyone going to a link of your question will see "your" and know that you are referring to the question author.

However, there is an argument to be made that since the answer is a direct response to the question, that attribution to the question asker is implicitly assumed. Therefore, you don't even need to mention or allude to the author at all.

This especially comes into play with answers that just modify the authors code. It's not their code, but it mostly is. Do they legally need explicit in text attribution?

My answer is no, because anyone can scroll up and see the question you are responding to. Any additional text would just be overly verbose.

But if the answer is yes:

1. That is really dumb
2. That rule is not worth enforcing

Comment: "That is really dumb". That pretty much sums it up for me :)

Answer (score 3):

The issue here seems to be finding a balance between proper attribution and, [as Henry Ecker puts it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412953/10871073)<sup>1</sup>, *noise*.

There are (probably) hundreds of thousands (if not millions) of questions on Stack Overflow in which a short excerpt of the question is included as a 'preamble' to the answer (or multiple such excerpts to delimit relevant sections of the answer).

Let's take [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69815009/10871073) I recently posted as an example<sup>2</sup> (the format I've used there is that generally used, especially in the tags I follow). Should this more properly be opened with attribution such as that shown below (the link is to the question)? In my opinion, this adds pointless noise – however, if it **is** legally required, I would start doing so (and would even run through my existing answers, to correct them).

---

[kuga asks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69814706/10871073):

> *Do I have to add my macro (MY_API) to the B class?*

If that `B` class is also …

---

Or how about in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69789121/10871073), where I have (quite appropriately, I feel) copy/pasted the OP's code and then edited that to demonstrate my answer. Should we be adding *explicit* attribution in such cases? And, if so, where? In the code block itself? (As we would – or *should* – when using a modified version of somebody else's code in one of our real-world projects.)

---

<sup>1</sup> For example, is attribution such as this required?

<sup>2</sup> I am using links to my own answers here to avoid any possibility that I may be seen as, in some way, calling out errors in other users' actions ([as was discussed earlier in SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/53427893#53427893)).

Comment: This is a really good demonstration of the question, but maybe not an answer?

Comment: @Trilarion Well, the question *does* have the `[discussion]` tag.

Comment: This is very much my point is that the attribution seems clunky in the context of the answer as the implicit understanding is that it is talking about the question it answers. Having said this, I would still like to know what is _required_ by the current policies/terms as written (whether or not the community believes they should or should not be enforced).

Comment: @AdrianMole Sure, and there is already one answer that says yes and one that says no. So your answer could represent the middle-ground between these two maybe. :)

Answer (score 2):

OK first of all I'm not a layer but here's my limited knowledge on the subject:

I think fair use would normally apply here (if we completely ignore other context) which would allow quoting the content for the purposes of critique or comment and therefore doesn't constitute a copyright violation, though claiming fair use for content that you could otherwise use by just providing attribution is a bit odd.

However making it obvious that it is fair use does imply that it's obvious where the content is from meaning it probably meets the attribution requirement anyway. Seeing that typically when you do want to comment on or critique something you will do it in such a way that it would make it obvious who said what is being commented on and where they said it so I guess overall it's a moot point.

Answer (score 1):

For me single questions and single answers are the elementary building blocks of the content here. The reason for that is that at a single time with a single edit, either a question or an answer is created or updated, assigning to that piece of content authorship and license. The "add" or "edit" button defines the basic content provision actions and define the scope of the base units.

Yes, there are logical associations between questions and answers, but legally I think they are irrelevant here.

The content license requires attribution (the founders could have chosen for example a Creative Commons variant without that requirement circumventing this behavior but didn't) and that of course applies regardless of whether it's convenient to do so or not.

That why I think that you have to give attribution if you use parts of other single building blocks (one for each question or answer from where you take content). A very clear yes here to attribution.

Now for how to actually do this:

In this case I think that "full attribution" in the way of title/url/author-name is indeed not required. The reason is that the Creative Commons license text gives a lot of leeway how attribution is performed (it speaks of "any reasonable manner based on .. context" ([3(a)(2)](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/legalcode)]. The old blog post by Jeff Atwood about [how to give attribution](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/) is actually more strict than the license itself. In this case I think that a simple "As stated in the question" or similar is fully sufficient (but still mandatory, not up to choice) because the title / location and author of the referred content is absolutely clear and also visible on the same page.

Why? Well, I think that the intention of the attribution requirement is to make sure it remains clear where content is taken from. As long as this purpose is achieved in a satisfying way, everything is okay.

Therefore I don't see it that critical. Just make sure that readers realize where the content comes from. Even a quote might be enough, although a few additional words like "From the question:" won't hurt either. And I would definitely not see them as noise.

Now, it's an interesting question that we aren't sure what a single work is and what the single content blocks are in legal terms, after more than 10 years of operations. It seems to be an oversight that this hasn't been clarified earlier. Is everything that's shown on one page a single block or everything that has some logical connection or everything that can be edited with a single edit or something else?

Answer (score -1):

...yes?

Put another way, you still have to cite your works in a scholarly document, no matter if you used part or all of that reference.  I don't see how that changes here.

If you reference something, you should mention:

- The person, by display name,
- A link to the reference, and
- The relevant sections you're quoting, with emphasis added at your discretion.

Comment: This was my initial assumption as well. In that the implicit understanding ("attribution") of the quote is only viable in the context of Stack Overflow (its "native environment" so to speak) and that that "implicit attribution" would be lost if the answer was copied or in some other way moved to isolate it from the question it answers. I just could not find any documents which explicitly mention quoting questions, when there is a significant amount of documents which explicitly mention answers.

Comment: Is an answer really like a *separate* document to the question? A Q&A pair seems more like different sections/chapters of the *same* document to me.

Comment: Assuming the case where the asker and answerer are different they would have separate licenses and would be legally distinct… also you can certainly copy from just the answer or just the question and those would have separate authors and source links… so I would assume yes they are separate documents… (?)

Comment: Does it depend on URL then? Because comments have the same URL as the question, with an additional fragment (/questions/<questionId>/<slug>#comment<commentId>_<postId>). An answer can be accessed via a separate URL (/a/<answerId>) or the same URL, with an additional path and fragment (/questions/<questionId>/<slug>/<answerId>#<answerId>). So answers could be considered as separate resources, or as part of the same resource, depending on how it's accessed...

Comment: @MisterMiyagi "A Q&A pair seems more like different sections/chapters of the same document to me" Another good question. If they were the same document, how can parts of the same document (like the question and every possible answer) then have different content licenses (versions of CC changed), depending on the time they were last edited.

Comment: So you are saying that nearly all answers on SO is doint things wrong!?

Comment: If I write an answer to a question, then quote three different sections of that question in my answer, do I then mention the question asker by name each time? Isn't that noisy? And if I can write my three quotes but only give attribution once in order to reduce the noise, how do I do it without making it seem like I have omitted the required attribution?

Comment: @VLAZ: I mean... *how* one has to do it is probably more the question that needs to be answered, but whether or not we have to is, I think, succinctly answered as "yes".  To be fair I have never in my 10 years on the network been called out for inappropriately citing a part of a question or another question - and I've done it in the **exact** manner I described in my question - so for those pundits who are breathlessly looking for someone to bludgeon for not following the rules, they haven't found it in me...

Comment: Yes to further clarify, I was specifically avoiding talking about "best practices for attribution" before I could get a definitive answer on _if_ attribution is required at all. I agree (and have included in the question body already) that I find adding this attribution to be noisy and would personally prefer the only quote/blockquote markdown style of attribution that is used almost everywhere on the site.

Comment: To the point of "So you are saying that nearly all answers on SO is doint things wrong!?" this is not the reason for this question. I am looking to learn what the _requirement_ is, not whether or not people are doing it correctly. Every country I've ever been to has people who drive over the speed limit and in some cases police will even not stop people who are doing so within certain parameters (on a multi-lane road/within a certain speed range above the limit). That does not make the speed limit not a requirement even if it is not, cannot, or should not be enforced for whatever reason.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi to continue you analogy, the answer is so intrinsically linked to the question that it's impossible have answers without questions.

Comment: This doesn't seem to make sense to me. The attribution link would lead you to the same page where you're already located.

Comment: @Ken White "The attribution link would lead you to the same page where you're already located." But a different location on that page and pages could potentially be very large. Maybe we should start with adding anchors to attribution links. After all that's how I link to comments, so maybe I should use this for answers and questions as well.

Comment: @Braiam "...it's impossible have answers without questions." In a logical sense yes, in a legal sense maybe not. An edit to an answer only influences that answer, not the related question. From the edit history and the license/author information displayed one could say that answers and questions are separate works on their own and could potentially be displayed also separately and may therefore need to attribute each other. Maybe it would be good if every answer would have a pointer to the question it answers (that would then act as attribution).

Comment: @Trilarion the document that is a Q&A pair, can't exist without the Q.

Comment: @Braiam "the document that is a Q&A pair, can't exist without the Q." But what does it mean? Hints to me that every answer really must point to its corresponding question. It's not a far way from having to know about the corresponding question to having to attribute that question too.

Comment: @Trilarion Preparing for an A without its Q seems not to be "reasonable". In principle content could be subdivided into *any* smaller parts, just like a document could be ripped into pages and smaller; there doesn't seem to be an end to how fractured content *could* be. Answers are written in the context of the question *and the context of [SO]'s rules/guidelines*, which means that the question can be reasonably expected not to disappear or change scope.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Interestingly, in the underlying databases, the parts of the "document" are spread all over. Comments, Questions, Answers are broken down and stored separately. I wonder what legal implications that logical correspondence you describe have. Couldn't I also say that the whole of SO is one big work and people constantly simply update it, so attribution requirements within it do not really make sense.

Comment: @Trilarion The internal, technical representation for automatic processing generally does not (IANAL, in my neck of the woods, etc.) impact how the content is *logically* treated. (There's a fun rabbit hole down to bits and bytes with caches and stuff. If your ``$DAYJOB``'s law department has a sense of humour, bring it up with them.) The logical framework presented by [so] on its webpage, rules and descriptions seems to be that of individual Q&As.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I fully agree with the logical structure of Qs and As but I also wonder if it has any meaningful implications beyond being ... some associations between different kind of contents. If so, maybe somebody could have spelt it out clearly at the beginning of it all. I can only repeat myself: What am I doing when editing content or adding content? To what am I adding content? There seem to be different interpretations possible but IANAL, so ...

Comment: @Trilarion: *different location on that page and pages could potentially be very large* doesn't make any sense either. The question asked here was whether quoting content of the question itself in an answer requires attribution. The same HTML page is presented for both the question and its answers, so they will clearly be on the same page, and since all answers are supposed to be addressing the original question, a reasonable conclusion can be drawn that any quoted text in the answer came from the question being answered. Adding attribution would simply be adding noise to the page.

Comment: And any content quoted that did not come from the original question would clearly need attribution, but that isn't the topic being discussed here.

Comment: @KenWhite "reasonable conclusion can be drawn that any quoted text in the answer came from the question being answered" You mean that all quoted text that is not attributed can be assumed to be from the same page? I'm not sure how reasonable that is. It leaves no room for error really. Better to be safe than sorry and add a bit of information about the whereabouts of quoted content. It's not just noise, it's actual information.